# Version compatibility between Solr and Zabbix

Tags: solr, zabbix

I am quite new to JMX and Zabbix. I want to setup an environment where I can monitor Solr instances using the same. 
However, I have different versions of Solr installed.

So, I wanted to ask is there any compatibility issue if I use the same zabbix template and version for different versions of Solr.

Comment: Probably note. But you can see Solr templates here https://github.com/akitogo/Zabbix-jmx-solr-template and https://github.com/Hackuracy/zabbix-solr-multicore

Comment: The different links are for the use case of monitoring multiple cores and a single core of Solr through Zabbix. They do not provide any insight for versioning at Solr. However, I think since Zabbix utilizes only on JMX, there shouldn't be any dependency between different versioning of Solr.